# Files in public folder not copying with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I wanted to add a second stylesheet to my app that would be loaded by the server instead of javascript.

So I placed the file in the `public` folder.  Then ran `craco start`.

It makes the `build` directory, with `index.html`, `asset-manifest.json`, and `static/`, but it isn't copying any other files I have in the `public` folder, such as the css I placed there, or the favicons that come packaged with cra.

Why isn't it copying the other files?

Note: I am overriding my webpack config with `craco` to turn `writeToDisk` on while in development.

```js
// craco.config.js

module.exports = {
    devServer: (devServerConfig, { env, paths, proxy, allowedHost }) => {
        devServerConfig.devMiddleware.writeToDisk = true;
        return devServerConfig;
    },
}
```

Comment: Do you run into the same issue of not copying all the files over from `public` when you run `craco build`?

Comment: @SteveHynding no, it seems to be copying them all when I run `build`.